# asp.net custom module is not being loaded?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, module, httpmodule

I created a custom module based on two articles:

http://community.devexpress.com/blogs/paulk/archive/2009/03/30/implementing-an-ihttpmodule.aspx

And the module based on:

[How do I display the duration it took to generate a page in a pages footer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3035584/how-do-i-display-the-duration-it-took-to-generate-a-page-in-a-pages-footer)

I have added the following class:

```
public class PerformanceMonitorModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PreRequestHandlerExecute += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //Set Page Timer Star
            HttpContext requestContext = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
            Stopwatch timer = new Stopwatch();
            requestContext.Items["Timer"] = timer;
            timer.Start();
        };
        context.PostRequestHandlerExecute += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            HttpContext httpContext = ((HttpApplication)sender).Context;
            HttpResponse response = httpContext.Response;
            Stopwatch timer = (Stopwatch)httpContext.Items["Timer"];
            timer.Stop();

            // Don't interfere with non-HTML responses
            if (response.ContentType == "text/html")
            {
                double seconds = (double)timer.ElapsedTicks / Stopwatch.Frequency;
                string result_time = string.Format("{0:F4} sec ", seconds);
                RenderQueriesToResponse(response, result_time);
            }
        };
    }
    void RenderQueriesToResponse(HttpResponse response, string result_time)
    {
        response.Write("<div style=\"margin: 5px; background-color: #FFFF00\"");
        response.Write(string.Format("<b>Page Generated in " + result_time));
        response.Write("</div>");
    }
    public void Dispose() { /* Not needed */ }
} // End of PerformanceMonitorModule
```

And the following to my web.config:

```
<system.web>
  ...
  <httpModules>
    <add name="PerformanceMonitorModule" type="PerformanceMonitorModule"/>
  </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

I have set breakpoints in the `PerformanceMonitorModule` classes init method and it never gets called.

A few notes:

- The website is running on HTTPS. I don't think this would make a difference though?
- The website is running in the Azure computer emulator. Not sure if this would cause any issues.
- I have tried putting the assembly qualified name (MySite.Website.Business.Modules.PerformanceMonitorModule, MySite.Website, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null).

I'm not sure what else to try in order to get this module to load?

Comment: Have you looked at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149004/httpmodule-wont-fire)?